# Error in SearchIndexer.exe drastically reduces performance of my machine

Tags: windows

I get the below error on my laptop and it drastically reduces the performance of my machine as the Indexer is constantly running. Please identify a solution except re-installation.

```
Faulting application name: SearchIndexer.exe, version: 7.0.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bcdd0
Faulting module name: TQUERY.DLL, version: 7.0.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdb21
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x0002e5c2
Faulting process id: 0xbe0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd0752bd78cce1
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\SearchIndexer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\TQUERY.DLL
Report Id: 16ce8a2f-7346-11e1-840a-a92a5ee507c3
EventID: 1000
```

Comment: Why not just turn off indexing?

Comment: Disable indexing.  You could also allow the indexing to complete.  Of course it should not be crashing so reinstalling your operating system is a good idea.

Comment: Windows XP or Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

- Click the Windows "start" button.
- Type `services.msc` into the "run" or "search" box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Find "Windows Search" in the list and click the Stop button.